# Spark DataFrame partition pruning on ORC files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning, orc

We have a `DataFrame` with `Transaction Date` column which is `timestamp`.

When we write the DF as `ORC` files we applied the partition logic on Transaction Date value **( not timestamp only date value)**, we created a separate field only for applying partition on that field.

If we read the ORC files again with where condition as Transaction Date(timestamp) value, will it prune the partitions?

Comment: Can you assess your findings based on my answer pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to reference the "separate" field appropriately. It stands to reason and is a fundamental DB rule wrt partition pruning.